# Posting an answer to my question after it's been closed as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-answer

I asked [NullReferenceException error in unity using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103462/nullreferenceexception-error-in-unity-using-c-sharp), which was marked as a duplicate. Later I found out where the problem is, but because it's marked as *duplicate* I can't answer my own question. Should I edit my question and add the answer as an edit to the question, or leave it without an answer? The [master duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is very general, and it seems that my answer is not fully in that question. (I voted to reopen my question already.)

Comment: I can't realy understand people downvote this , It's a discussion question . if you have an idea please tell me , downvote and either upvote will not help me and others!!

Comment: @rene , no I didn't know that , Thanks!

Comment: To be successful pass the re-open queue you have to edit your question so it become clear why the duplicate isn't applicable.

Comment: Your explanation why the generic duplicate does not apply is not really good. So why again does the answer to the duplicate not also answer your question? Also I think the question itself is not very useful. You are not giving a minimal but runnable example, just some code excerpts, making it unsolvable for anyone else. I doubt others would learn much from it. However, it's nice you found the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I closed your question because it's one of the *many* `NullReferenceException` questions we see everyday, where the asker seems unable to solve the problem by himself. These issues are usually trivial to solve, either with a trained eye or with a debugger.

The canonical question on the topic gives *a lot* of detailed instructions on how to pinpoint the issue and solve the problem. It's meant to be helpful for a lot of different cases. Remember we're trying to be helpful to a lot of people here, not only the OP.

The goal of closing your question as a duplicate was precisely to give you the tools you need to find the issue by yourself, so the next time you get such an error you'll know exactly what to do.

In your case I can tell that `gameController` is `null`, or `scoreText` is `null` and you're using a Release build with inlined functions. Unless there's some Unity voodoo involved which would cause the use of a `call` opcode instead of `callvirt` to call the `OnTriggerEnter` function, allowing it to be called with a `null` `this` reference, but I doubt it.

Nevertheless, I appreciate the fact that you're willing to answer your own question for the benefit of other users. I don't know Unity but as you say it may be a common mistake, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and reopen it, so feel free to post your answer.

Answer (score 13):

Rather than looking at how general the canonical answer is, look at whether it answers your question. The close voter felt it did, and it sounds like you feel it doesn't.

The appropriate response here is to edit your question to show *how* it doesn't.

List out a couple of the things the canonical question suggests to try, explain that you tried them, and pertinently, explain why they didn't help you find the problem.

If you edit those in, your question will likely be reopened, and will likely be a better resource for future readers with similar issues, who can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the answer it should be easy to convert question from duplicate of "What is NRE" to some specific question.

There is no point to add text like you've added which is essentially "not duplicate as I don't like it". It is much better to incorporate it in question. In this particular case something like "I expect `Start` to be called, but it does not, which indeed leads to NRE (as explained in [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it))".